# How to send data to servlet from android application in android studio?

Tags: java, android, servlets

I want to send data from my android app to servlet.
i was trying to use this in my app :

```
    private boolean postData(String s) {
    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();

    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(s); // s is my url

    try {

        List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("id", "1003"));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("name", "Anil"));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("loc", "Kalyan"));
        httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
    }  catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

I was this method but was not able to import these files :

```
    import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
    import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
    import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
```

How to impoert these files in android studio?? Or else is there any other method to do so??  Thanx in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Android 6.0 release removes support for the Apache HTTP client. If your app is using this client and targets Android 2.3 (API level 9) or higher, use the HttpURLConnection class instead

```
 URL url = new URL(path);
 HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
 conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
 conn.setConnectTimeout(10000);
 conn.setReadTimeout(2000);
 conn.setDoOutput(true);
 byte[] bypes = params.toString().getBytes();
 conn.getOutputStream().write(bypes);
 InputStream inStream = conn.getInputStream();
```

Comment: Thanx @lynn518, I have never used this can u send me some example of sending data to servlet through android and how to recieve it?

Comment: I am very happy to do so, but I am so sorry I don't know how to send to you

Comment: If you could mail me? @ roverma1094@gmail.com or else link some example plz

Comment: I have sent some links to your mailbox, hope they can help you

Comment: Thanx will try it out:)